# Is this normal for JBoss EAP server?

Tags: multithreading, jboss, jboss-eap-6

Heap Usage (mb)

Metric  Actual
Max:
8126
Used:
2526
(31%)
Committed:
8126
Init:
8192
Non Heap Usage (mb)
Metric  Actual
Max:
2144
Used:
200 
(9%)
Committed:
326 
Init:
23
Thread Usage
Need Help?
Metric  Actual
Live:
585 
Daemon:
557 (95%)

I've already setup my server using these configuration:

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms8g -Xmx8g -XX:MaxPermSize=2g -XX:+UseParallelGC"
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" 
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman"
```

My problem is that sometimes the server will hang on itself and I need to restart it manually. Thread Usage always above 90% when the server started. Is it normal? What should I do to avoid this kind of problem and what are the causes ?

Answer (score 1):

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=2g
```

This is very high

```
-Xms8g -Xmx8g -XX:+UseParallelGC"
```

This accepts 8 second full GC pauses.

```
Thread Usage always above 90% when the server started
```

What do you mean by this?

Then you'll need to figure out what happens when "hang on itself". Check the CPU usage of the Java process when this happens.
When there is no almost usage it could be a deadlock or the application could waiting on something else. A thread dump will help you here.
When it is high it could either be Java or GC related. Have a look at gc logs and run a profiler like async-profiler.
Also have a look at other system activity like swapping.

Comment: I checked my metric on JBOSS management console and it shows under Thread Usage > metric > daemon, and it was always 90 % on that time. Did you mean this is too high -> -XX:MaxPermSize=2g ?  What should it be then for production application?
Thanks

Comment: @MohdFidzrin 512 MB is already a lot but this is unlikely the cause of your problems

Comment: I see, in a simple word, how do you describe what -XX:MaxPermSize do? 
More likely I need to study more on what are these configurations does before simply changing anything on the server.

Comment: Metaspace is where all the Java classes and Java class metadata lives. 2GB would imply that you have hundreds of thousands of classes loaded. Typically even large Java application only have tens of thousands of classes loaded. But this is not your main issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling explicit GC collection and run your own GC . In this way , the unwanted and unused garbage will be cleared .
Something like this:(Sample config for Jboss + 8Gb RAM server with a web app)

```
JAVA_OPTS="-server -Xms7800m -Xmx7800m -XX:NewSize=5632m -XX:MaxNewSize=5632m -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:MetaspaceSize=128m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=256m -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=50 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:ConcGCThreads=4 -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -Xloggc:/mydirectory/project/projectgclog-$(date +%Y_%m_%d-%H_%M).log -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

By this way , my server periodically sweeps out the unwanted garbage and lets the server run without any error.
Hope this helps.